# Rest Api Magento 2 customer search by custom Attribute

Tags: rest, api, magento2

i have created a custom attribute "customer_number" in the customer.
i want to filter using this custom attribute

```
$userData = array("username" => "abc", "password" => "123");
$ch = curl_init("http://example.com/api/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);

$ch = curl_init("http://example.com/api/index.php/rest/V1/customers/search?searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=email&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=asc&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=customer_number&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=1234567890"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

No Result is Coming...

For Updating the Customer_number I used like below

```
$custom_attribute[] =  array('attribute_code'=>'customer_number','value'=>'6666666666');

 $customerData = [
'customer' => [
     "id" => 2,
    "email" => "xxx@gmail.com",
    "firstname" => "Umar",
    "lastname" => "Rafsan",
    "storeId" => 1,
    "websiteId" => 1,
    "custom_attributes" => $custom_attribute
]
```

];

```
//Get customer info
$ch = curl_init("http://example.com/api/rest/V1/customers/me");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT"); // Get method
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($customerData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```